# GetBytes with argument of sbyte type

Tags: c#

Why GetBytes returns array of two elements instead of array of one element, although storage of sbyte takes only 1 byte.

```
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes((sbyte)127)
```

Comment: It seems from looking at the bit that it casts to `short` before converting to bytes. I can't tell you why it does this or how to get it to convert to a byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetBytes` does not have [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `sbyte`, so your `sbyte` is being implicitly converted to `short` and you call `GetBytes(short)`, which returns two bytes.

You should simply cast your `sbyte` to a `byte` with [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) conversion.

```
sbyte s = 127;
byte[] byteArray = new[] { (byte)s };
```